# Which organism has undergone the least evolutionary change?

Tags: evolution

A favorite documentary of mine is *[Encounters at the End of the World](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1093824/)*, in where, *"Film-maker **Werner Herzog** travels to the McMurdo Station in **Antarctica**, looking to **capture the continent's beauty and investigate the characters living there**."*

During his time there, he films under-ice divers who risk their lives to explore the depths of antartica's ocean waters to study organisms that are believed to have not evolved for millions (if not billions) of years.

> I noticed that the divers, in their routine, were not speaking at all. To me,
>   they were like priests preparing for mass. Under the ice, the divers find themselves in a separate reality, where space and time acquire a strange new dimension.

[image]

> One of the foremost scholars in the world in his field, Dr. Pawlowski, studies the DNA sequences of foraminifera. What looks esoteric is in fact one of the fundamental questions about life on Earth. In the same way that cosmologists search for the origins of the universe, **the scientists here are tracing back the evolution of life to its earliest stages**.

[image: antartica underwater life1]

While watching this part of the documentary, it always makes me wonder: **Which form of live (lineage of organism) has undergone the *least* evolutionary change**? And how exactly is this quantified - just differences in DNA/RNA?

Comment: Since when? Since LUCA? I doubt we know nearly enough about LUCA (and about the origins of viruses) to be conclusive. I very much doubt that genetic pairwise differences would help as I doubt any extant species would align with LUCA (even if we were to know LUCA's genome). If we use phenotypes, then it is likely going to be quite arbitrary as to what trait we decide to put attention into (and again, we don't know much about LUCA's phenotype).

Comment: Yes, I suppose since LUCA, or some evolutionary period around then. And yeah, I'm sure we don't have nearly as much data as we'd like to have.. however, is there a "front runner" as of now - an organism that currently holds the title? I did come across [this](http://newsroom.ucla.edu/releases/scientists-discover-organism-that-hasnt-evolved-in-more-than-2-billion-years), but I'm not sure if there are others.

Comment: [Here](http://www.pnas.org/content/112/7/2087) is the original article. Looks like worth having a look. I don't know how they can make statement that these species went through such a long stasis.

Comment: @Remi.b Right.. I'm not too versed in this field. Do you (or anyone) know exactly how these evolutionary comparisons are made in a quantitative way?

Comment: No, I don't. But I suspect many users will be able to read this paper and eventually come up with an answer to your question. I might do it later if I find the time.

Comment: @Remi.b *"For extant prokaryotes, phylogenetic relations and physiological characteristics can be determined by molecular biology backed by growth experiments. For fossil communities, however, the biomolecules required (DNA, rRNA, enzymes, etc.) have been lost during preservation. Thus, analyses of fossil communities such as those described here must rely on evidence provided by proxies—the morphometrics of the preserved fossils backed by studies of their regional and local geological setting and their paleoecology and community fabric."* -- is this kind of analysis reliable enough?

Comment: Indeed. It will still give food for thoughts and may provide interesting insights to your question.

Comment: You are asking the question, so it's your job to define what you mean, not to ask others "how it is quantitate". And do you really mean "live"? More effort on that and less on eye-candy might have led to a better question.

Comment: @David As I previously mentioned, I'm not familiar with measurements and standards that are practiced in this field, so I'm not sure what to even define, and is the reason for me asking :)

Comment: @David Well, I do have the ability the edit the question, so.. :) And I'm not sure I know what you're referring to when you reference "live".. some more specificity would be appreciated. Also, I wanted to share my enjoyment for the documentary..theres nothing wrong with a couple pictures, I'm sure most would agree..

Comment: Has mixed reviews, but there's a lay book [*Survivors* by Richard Fortey](https://www.amazon.ca/Survivivors-Animals-Plants-That-Behind/dp/0007209878/ref=tmm_pap_swatch_0?_encoding=UTF8&qid=1503524034&sr=1-1) that looks at some examples of organisms that have undergone the minimal evolutionary change over time.